# Property 'startHeaderHeight' doesnot exist error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for my react native project. The project is running fine. But in this image why there is the underline in the code. When I hover onto it I get

```
"[ts] Property 'startHeaderHeight' does not exist on type 'Explore'.
any"
```

[image: red underline]

Answer (score 0):

This is a TypeScript error, not a React error Typescript don't maintain React TS definitions.

[refer here ans from gaearon](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12519)

Comment: Yes I have tried defining it to constuctor but i still get red underlines

Comment: yes its working fine. I am curious why this red underline coming in visual studio code ..

Comment: my be you have to run `npm install @types/react@latest`